# How to refresh the contents in a folder using c#?

Tags: c#

My objective is to refresh my saved file in a folder to show the last modified date on it.Because with out refreshing it does not shows the last modified date on hover.So is there any way to refresh the files in a folder using c#?

Any help will really appreciated

Comment: Please show your code - how do you get last modified date on hover?

Comment: While hover on that file in folder it shows wrong modified time.Only after refreshing it shows correct time

Comment: How your question related to C# and programming?

Comment: Is there a way to refresh a folder by code?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SHChangeNotify` function to tell the explorer that a file has changed.

```
    public void NotifyItemChanged(string fullPath)
    {
        NativeMethods.SHChangeNotify(
            SHChangeNotifyEvents.UpdateItem,
            SHChangeNotifyFlags.PathW | SHChangeNotifyFlags.NotifyRecursive,
            fullPath,
            null);
    }

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern void SHChangeNotify(SHChangeNotifyEvents eventID, SHChangeNotifyFlags flags, string path, string path2);

[Flags]
public enum SHChangeNotifyEvents : uint
{
    RenameItem = 0x00000001,
    Create = 0x00000002,
    Delete = 0x00000004,
    MkDir = 0x00000008,
    RmDir = 0x00000010,
    MediaInserted = 0x00000020,
    MediaRemoved = 0x00000040,
    DriveRemoved = 0x00000080,
    DriveAdd = 0x00000100,
    NetShare = 0x00000200,
    NetUnshare = 0x00000400,
    Attributes = 0x00000800,
    UpdateDir = 0x00001000,
    UpdateItem = 0x00002000,
    ServerDisconnect = 0x00004000,
    UpdateImage = 0x00008000,
    DriveAddGui = 0x00010000,
    RenameFolder = 0x00020000,
    FreeSpace = 0x00040000,
    ExtendedEvent = 0x04000000,
    AssocChanged = 0x08000000,
    DiskEvents = 0x0002381F,
    GlobalEvents = 0x0C0581E0,
    AllEvents = 0x7FFFFFFF,
    Interrupt = 0x80000000
}

public enum SHChangeNotifyFlags : uint
{
    IdList = 0x0000,
    PathA = 0x0001,
    PrinterA = 0x0002,
    Dword = 0x0003,
    PathW = 0x0005,
    PrinterW = 0x0006,
    Type = 0x00FF,
    Flush = 0x1000,
    FlushNoWait = 0x3000,
    NotifyRecursive = 0x10000
}
```

Note: in Windows XP, this will refresh the whole folder, not just the specified file.

Comment: I have tried this format as filepath ("E:\\FolderName").But refreshing not works

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
FileInfo.LastWriteTime
```

in a loop every `t` time.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to refresh your directoryview you can just do `Directory.GetFiles()`